# Python Pandas: Passing arguments to a function in agg()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to reduce data in a pandas dataframe by using different kind of functions and argument values. However, I did not manage to change the default arguments in the aggregation functions. Here is an example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,np.nan,2,1],
...                    'y': ['a','a','b','b']})
>>> df
     x  y
0  1.0  a
1  NaN  a
2  2.0  b
3  1.0  b
```

Here is an aggregation function, for which I would like to test different values of `b`:

```
>>> def translate_mean(x, b=10):
...   y = [elem + b for elem in x]
...   return np.mean(y)
```

In the following code, I can use this function with the default `b` value, but I would like to pass other values:

```
>>> df.groupby('y').agg(translate_mean)
      x
y
a   NaN
b  11.5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48843887/4050261

Comment: I believe this might help.
https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just in case you have multiple columns, and you want to apply different functions and different parameters for each column, you can use lambda function with agg function.
For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,np.nan,2,1],
...                    'y': ['a','a','b','b']
                       'z': ['0.1','0.2','0.3','0.4']})
>>> df
     x  y  z
0  1.0  a  0.1
1  NaN  a  0.2
2  2.0  b  0.3
3  1.0     0.4

>>> def translate_mean(x, b=10):
...   y = [elem + b for elem in x]
...   return np.mean(y)
```

To groupby column 'y', and apply function translate_mean with b=10 for col 'x'; b=25 for col 'z', you can try this:

```
df_res = df.groupby(by='a').agg({
    'x': lambda x: translate_mean(x, 10),
    'z': lambda x: translate_mean(x, 25)})
```

Hopefully, it helps.

Answer (score 20):

Just pass as arguments to `agg` (this works with `apply`, too).

```
df.groupby('y').agg(translate_mean, b=4)
Out: 
     x
y     
a  NaN
b  5.5
```

Comment: Short of using lambas, is this possible when aggregating across multiple functions? e.g, `df.groupby('y').agg([translate_mean, translate_mean])` and I want to translate by first 4, then 8?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can try using `apply` in this case:

```
df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: translate_mean(x['x'], 20))
```

Now the result is:

```
y
a     NaN
b    21.5
```