# Passing argument in groupby.agg with multiple functions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

Anyone knows how to pass arguments in a groupby.agg() with **multiple** functions?

Bottom line, I would like to use it with a custom function, but I will ask my question using a built-in function needing an argument.

Assuming:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
np.random.seed(15)
day = datetime.date.today()
day_1 = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
day_2 = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(2)
day_3 = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(3)
ticker_date = [('fi', day), ('fi', day_1), ('fi', day_2), ('fi', day_3),
               ('di', day), ('di', day_1), ('di', day_2), ('di', day_3)]
index_df = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ticker_date, names=['lvl_1', 'lvl_2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8), index_df, ['value'])
```

**How would I do this:**

```
df.groupby('lvl_1').agg(['min','max','quantile'])
```

**with, as argument for 'quantile':**

```
q = 0.22
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `lambda` function:

```
q = 0.22
df1 = df.groupby('lvl_1')['value'].agg(['min','max',lambda x: x.quantile(q)])
print (df1)
            min       max  <lambda>
lvl_1                              
di     0.275401  0.530000  0.294589
fi     0.054363  0.848818  0.136555
```

Or is possible create `f` function and set it name for custom column name:

```
q = 0.22
f = lambda x: x.quantile(q)
f.__name__ = 'custom_quantile'
df1 = df.groupby('lvl_1')['value'].agg(['min','max',f])
print (df1)
            min       max  custom_quantile
lvl_1                                     
di     0.275401  0.530000         0.294589
fi     0.054363  0.848818         0.136555
```

Comment: Awesome, second time you help me out! I like the second option because it will help me a lot given that bottom line, I am looking to set custom functions! Thanks mate

Comment: Is there a practical difference between creating a named lambda, or just using a def statement?

Comment: @RedPanda - in my opinion `def` is more common, but is is same with some [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577016)

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df.groupby('lvl_1')['value'].agg(['min','max',("custom_quantile",lambda x: x.quantile(q))])
```

for q=0.22, the output is:

```
       min      max         custom_quantile
lvl_1           
di     0.275401 0.530000    0.294589
fi     0.054363 0.848818    0.136555
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.

Comment: It works (edited output), and is similar to the first option in jerzael's answer, although it's a bit better (naming the column inline).

Comment: Providing output which makes the "it works, honest" more plausible is appreciated. However, an explanation of how it works and why it is supposed to help would be better. StackOverflow is about sharing knowledge and helping people to understand. Not for providing code to solve problems (tested or not). Please help to fight the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a platform for finding unpaid programmers to do work for others.