# how to rename a header under a groupby

Tags: pandas

this is the dtype of my dataframe:

```
tradePrice         first               float64
                   amax                float64
                   amin                float64
                   last                float64
                   <lambda>            float64
tradeVolume        <lambda>              int64
                   sum                   int64
                   mean                float64
```

I am trying to rename the name of the  headers and I can not do this within the groupby.
How can I rename it in the dataframe?

Comment: Can you give an excerpt of your dataframe, e.g. print df.head(5) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rename`.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'amin':'new'}, level=1)
```

For rename `lambda`s use `__name__` (check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843971/2901002) with data):

```
f1 = lambda x: function1
f1.__name__ == 'custom_name1'

f2 = lambda x: function2
f2.__name__ == 'custom_name2'
```